Is there an existing PyArrow method to convert a PyArrow COO Tensor to a PyArrow CSR Tensor?
I can see that PyArrow has an object called SparseCOOTensor. Is it possible to convert it into a Sparse CSR/CSC Matrix or do I need to write a custom function to do that?
Looking for something similar to the SciPy library sparse matrix conversions.

The documentation is totally lacking on this topic (opened an issue for it: https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/43352, contributions are very welcome!).
If I look at the tests I can find some examples you could work with: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/c3ebdf500e75ca868f50b7d374fc8ce2237756b8/python/pyarrow/tests/test_sparse_tensor.py#L238
There are methods like to/from_tensor(), to/from_numpy() and to/from_scipy() implemented that you can use: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/c3ebdf500e75ca868f50b7d374fc8ce2237756b8/python/pyarrow/tensor.pxi#L605
